# How to preprocess a C source code for pycparser

Tags: c, c++

I need to parse my C and C++ codes with [pycparser](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser), but it needs to be stripped of preprocessor directives and comments before.

So, do you know any way to do this? I've found [CPP](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cpp) preprocessor, but I have no idea, if I can use it just like that, without "full" preprocessing.

I've found a tool [unifdef](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unifdef) too, which seems to do exactly what I want, but only with preprocessor conditionals (e.g. *#ifdef*).

I don't want to write this tool by myself, because it's going to be used with a pretty large project, so I want to use something really sophisticated.

---

#### My attempts:

I've tried to find places, where was the function `test` called in this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// asdfdsa
/* sadfsd
 * 
 */

void test() {
    printf("asd");
}

int main() {

    test();

    test();

    return 0;
}
```

I preprocessed this code with command `gcc -E -std=c99 test.c -o testP.c` and then I tried to find function calls with this Python code:

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
# pycparser: func_defs.py
#
# Using pycparser for printing out all the calls of some function
# in a C file.
#
# Copyright (C) 2008-2015, Eli Bendersky
# License: BSD
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

# This is not required if you've installed pycparser into
# your site-packages/ with setup.py
sys.path.extend(['.', '..'])

from pycparser import c_parser, c_ast, parse_file


# A visitor with some state information (the funcname it's
# looking for)
#
class FuncCallVisitor(c_ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self, funcname):
        self.funcname = funcname

    def visit_FuncCall(self, node):
        if node.name.name == self.funcname:
            print('%s called at %s' % (self.funcname, node.name.coord))


def show_func_calls(filename, funcname):
    ast = parse_file(filename, use_cpp=True)
    v = FuncCallVisitor(funcname)
    v.visit(ast)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) > 2:
        filename = sys.argv[1]
        func = sys.argv[2]
    else:
        filename = 'test.c'
        func = 'test'

    show_func_calls(filename, func)
```

but still, I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "func_calls.py", line 46, in <module>
    show_func_calls(filename, func)
  File "func_calls.py", line 33, in show_func_calls
    ast = parse_file(filename, use_cpp=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pycparser/__init__.py", line 93, in parse_file
    return parser.parse(text, filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pycparser/c_parser.py", line 146, in parse
    debug=debuglevel)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pycparser/ply/yacc.py", line 265, in parse
    return self.parseopt_notrack(input,lexer,debug,tracking,tokenfunc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pycparser/ply/yacc.py", line 1047, in parseopt_notrack
    tok = self.errorfunc(errtoken)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pycparser/c_parser.py", line 1691, in p_error
    column=self.clex.find_tok_column(p)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pycparser/plyparser.py", line 55, in _parse_error
    raise ParseError("%s: %s" % (coord, msg))
pycparser.plyparser.ParseError: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include/stdarg.h:40:27: before: __gnuc_va_list
```

Comment: So basically you want all lines starting with # or /* or // thrown out, correct? Why not use sed?

Comment: @schaiba I want to remove even nested directives etc. To be honest, I've never used `sed` before, so I don't know much about its abilities :-)

Comment: What's your problem with `cpp`?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with this?! Preprocessed source is *hard* to work with, as it is littered with the (often bletcherous) expansions of macros like `getchar()` and definitions by messy constant expressions of certain constants.

Comment: @vonbrand it looks like the stripping and `cpp` processing would be an intermediate step as part of the pycparser toolchain to generate cross-references.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`pycparser` documentation specifically [says](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser#interaction-with-the-c-preprocessor) you should use `cpp` or `gcc -E` to prepare source code for parsing. So the "full" preprocessing is not an *issue* of `cpp`, it's the feature you need in order to run `pycparser` on your code.

If you simply strip your code of all preprocessor directives, parsing will fail because of undeclared types (like `int32_t` or `size_t`) and library functions missing prototypes.

EDIT: `pycparser` only supports C99 syntax. If `gcc` takes your code for C++ for some reason, run the preprocessor like this:

```
gcc -E -std=c99
```

EDIT2: it seems that you're getting more errors related to compiler-specific symbols. Try to use the ["fake" headers](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser#what-about-the-standard-c-library-headers) provided by `pycparser`:

```
gcc -E -std=c99 -I/path/to/pycparser/utils/fake_libc_include
```

Comment: I've tried both `gcc -E` and `cpp -E`, but I'm getting the error `pycparser.plyparser.ParseError: /usr/include/stdio.h:29:8: before: "C"`

Comment: Do your sources have `.cpp` extension? `gcc` seems to treat your code as C++ for some reason, and `pycparser` only supports C.

Comment: I tried compiling it with `-std=c99`, but still the same result... My code has `.c` expansion. I've described my attempt more thoroughly in the question.

Comment: It's **not** the same result, you've got a totally different error message now. Check the update to my answer.

Comment: Great! Thak you very much, "fake headers" solved it finally!